# rosbridge_websocket.launch on fuerte

Tags: ros, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried following [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality), but rosbridge_websocket.launch doesn't seem to exist, at least not on fuerte.

Is there another way to get things going in fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62226/rosbridge_websocket.launch-on-fuerte/) by [tjpalmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4834/tjpalmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the documentation on the Wiki is for Groovy.  Try this instead for Fuerte:

```
$ roslaunch rosbridge_launch full.launch
```

This launch file also launches a web server (roswww) so you can test rosbridge in your web browser on port 8000.  (You will probably see a warning when running the full.launch file that permission is denied for running the webserver on port 80 so it runs it on port 8000 instead.)

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjpalmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4834/tjpalmer/) on 2013-05-08**:
I've tried that out, and it works like you said (including the warning). Thanks much for the help.